# KIVY - Rotate the whole Layout

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I would like to ask if is even possible to rotate whole Layout in Kivy (including its functionality).

I need to have designed one Layout but I need to create an app with splited screen horizontally and use that Layout on bottom side normaly, but on the top side rotated by **180°** (upside down)...

The problem is that even it looks good, the functionality on the up side (which is upside down) still stays normal (in this case: When I click on **Button 2** the **Button 1** is clicked and vice versa - that's bad... )

[image: Layout example]

My code for Kivy is here:

```py
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            PushMatrix
            Rotate:
                angle: 180
                origin: self.center
        canvas.after:
            PopMatrix
        Test:

    Test:

<Test@BoxLayout>:
    Button:
        text: "Button 1"
    Button:
        text: "Button 2"
```

Please, could You somebody give some advice how to solve it?

Thank You a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.

Thank to all of You but I've solved it by myself?

Sorry for this topic but if would somebody interested, the solution is in the using of another Layout ('ScatterLayout').

Here is the solution:

```py
BoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    BoxLayout:
        Test:
            rotation: 180

    Test:

<Test@ScatterLayout>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            text: "Button 1"
        Button:
            text: "Button 2"
```